# Create a region which pops up on click on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically want to create a region in a webpage that pops out (i.e. on clicking something, it overlaps a part of the webpage).
okay, so what I did is created a `div` and set its z-index greater than all other elements. 
Then I used jQuery

```
$("#myElement").hide();
```

in the beginning and using jQuery, I made it to show using the onclick. Everything is perfect till now but this approach lacks fluidity. 
What I mean by fluidity is that the showing and hiding of the region doesn't involves any effect. 
So my question is, Is this approach correct? Moreover, Can I add some kind of animation to make the showing and hiding a bit more interesting?

Comment: There is no right or wrong. jQuery has numerous animation methods (look in the API), or you can use css3 transitions or animations

Comment: Essentially, you are talking about creating a modal dialog.  There are numerous ways to do it with JavaScript/jQuery.  You can also do that using only HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). This should get you started with making things more interesting.

Here's an example of something basic that adds some effect.

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('div').show('slow');
});
```

[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZPGj/)

Answer (score 1):

Charlie's suggestion of CSS3 transitions is a good one, since they probably offer the most flexibility as to the precise details of the animation and are often smoother than jQuery animations.

Only trick with them is that you can't animate an element to/from `display: none` (and note that jQuery's `.hide()` sets `display` to `none`, meaning you can't combine an animation with these jQuery methods).  There are a lot of other ways to do it, however. See, e.g., [this blog post](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337) that discusses the issue.

You can also have the "hidden" state translated a couple thousand pixels offscreen and the "visible" state set to `transform: initial`.  Note that if you use this solution, you'll probably need to use some sort of custom bezier curve for the transition timing function (for which [this tool](http://cubic-bezier.com/) might be helpful).

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous approaches to show element which CSS display property is set to `none` e.g.

[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
$('#myElement').show(600, 'linear');
```

[.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

```
$('#myElement').fadeIn(600, 'linear');
```

[.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

```
$('#myElement').fadeTo(600, 1.0, 'linear');
```

but if you want some special animation then be creative with CSS & jQuery e.g.

```
#myElement {
  background: #999;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;    
}
```

---

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('#myElement').show().stop().animate({ width: '200px', height: '200px', margin: '-125px 0 0 -125px' }, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
```

[FIDDLE for example above](http://jsfiddle.net/9RMR6/2/)

***Note:** For complete list of easing effects click [here](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html)